# Problema updating and uploading my apk

Tags: android, xml, versioning

Hi guys this is the first update I make to my app... I was reading and noticed that I need to change the versionCode and versionNameof my app in the manifest.xml, I did this and click on Build-> Generate Signed APK then in the developer console select my app and in the left menu click on APK then upload new APK and select my new generated APK but I keep getting the same error:

> Upload error You must use another version code for your APK because
>   you already have a file with the version code 1.

BUT I don't know why I'm getting this error this is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ve.net.gorydev.bachaqueofamilia"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

what should I change?? remember this is my first update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versionCode and versionName are also defined in your app/build.gradle; define them there and you should have no problems.

```
android {
     defaultConfig{
          versionCode 2
          versionName "1.1"
     }
}
```